# Find the Thevenin equivalent circuit for a basic RC circuit with a dependent current source

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, current-source

[image]

Source: Linear Circuits Time Domains, Phasor, and Laplace Transform Approaches Third Edition.

author: Raymond A. DeCarlo, Pen Min Lin

Publisher: Kendall Hunt Publishing Company

I found this example in a textbook. How does this circuit convert to a Thevenin equivalent circuit through the standard way? We can treat the capacitor as a voltage source, Vth = 10V.  How about Rth? From the voltage source, I can only see 4 ohm resistor parallel to the source.

My solution:
Vx/R = C*dVc/dt + S*Vx (KCL)

Vx/4 = 0.25*dVc/dt + 0.75*Vx

dVc/dt + 2*Vx = 0

dVc/dt + 2*Vc = 0, Vx = Vc

Therefore, Vc(t) = exp(2*(t-t0))*Vc(t0)

= exp(2*(t))*10 u(t) V, at t > 0, t0 = 0

From that, we can find Rth = -2 ohm. Vth is 10V at t = 0.

Answer (score 0):

These are the currents (in blue boxes) that flow when 10 volts is applied: -

[image]

I'm using a simulator as a visual aide to solving the problem. So, with 5 amps flowing back into the 10 volt source, the Thevenin resistance has to be **negative** 2 Ω.

But, we can simplify the circuit and remove the 4 Ω resistor: -

[image]

Now, we have 7.5 amps back-feeding the supply and that is a Thevenin resistance of -1.333 Ω. We can also combine the Thevenin resistance of -1.333 Ω with the +4 Ω that we removed. We use the resistor paralleling formula: -

$$R\hspace{1cm}=\hspace{1cm}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{-1.3333}}\hspace{1cm}=\hspace{1cm} -2\text{ ohm}$$

So, it boils down to how we analyse the voltage dependent current source and clearly, for every ten volts applied it outputs 7.5 amps back into whatever is providing the 10 volts (as per \$g_m\cdot V_s\$ shown in your question).

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming associated reference directions) an element that has a current +gm*i when a voltage v is applied can be modeled as a resistor of value 1/gm.

So if the current is -gm*i the element can be modeled as a resistor of value -1/gm.